# How to /WAIT A SECOND/ to navigate after user signed in in a restricted route?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, react-router-dom

So what I mean is, I have a functionality of after user signed in, navigate him/her to the homepage in a second, such as:

```
const handleSignIn = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const user = await signIn(formData);

    if (user) {
      toast.success('Signed In!');

      setTimeout(() => {
        navigate('/');
      }, 1000);
    } else {
      toast.error('Bad user credentials!');
    }
  };
```

But, I built a protected route, such as:

```
function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      setIsLoading(true);

      if (user) {
        setUser(user);
      } else {
        setUser(null);
      }

      setIsLoading(false);
    });

    return unsubscribe;
  }, []);

  if (isLoading) return <Spinner />;

  return (
    <>
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/' element={<PrivateRoute />}>
            <Route index element={<Explore />} />
            <Route path='/offers' element={<Offers />} />
            <Route path='/profile' element={<Profile />} />
            <Route path='/contact/:landlordId' element={<Contact />} />
            <Route path='/create-listing' element={<CreateListing />} />
            <Route path='/category/:categoryName' element={<Category />} />
            <Route path='/category/:categoryName/:id' element={<Listing />} />
          </Route>
          <Route
            path='/sign-in'
            element={!user ? <SignIn /> : <Navigate to='/' />}
          />
          <Route
            path='/sign-up'
            element={!user ? <SignUp /> : <Navigate to='/' />}
          />
          <Route
            path='/forgot-password'
            element={!user ? <ForgotPassword /> : <Navigate to='/' />}
          />
        </Routes>
        {user && <Navbar />}
      </Router>

      <ToastContainer autoClose={1000} />
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

So the problem here is, whenever user signs in or signs out,the **onAuthStateChanged** gets executed, therefore it enforce app to re-render in order to understand who's logged in and logged out then behave accordingly, like restrict some routes and allow others.

When user signs in, I'd like to show some toast message BUT it triggers the App level state and before I show toast and navigate user, it automatically navigates user into the homepage due to the restriction, how can I wait a second before doing that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can't you just wait for x amount of time before calling `setUser()`? That is because `setUser()` updates the `user` value, which triggers navigation.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
        setIsLoading(true);

        setTimeout(() => {
            if (user) {
                setUser(user);
            } else {
                setUser(null);
            }

            setIsLoading(false);
        }, 1000);
    });

    return unsubscribe;
}, []);
```

Alternatively, use async/await with a custom `wait` async function that will avoid nesting:

```
const wait = async (d) => new Promise(r => setTimeout(d, r));

useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, async (user) => {
        setIsLoading(true);

        await wait(1000);

        if (user) {
            setUser(user);
        } else {
            setUser(null);
        }

        setIsLoading(false);
    });

    return unsubscribe;
}, []);
```

Comment: Although this seems to be working, one major problem is whenever user logs in, logs out or even refresh the page, this code will run and I don't want them to stall one second when they can load the page immediately, but I'll mark this as accepted because you gave me a point thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Allow the `SignIn`, component to handle the redirect itself. You have two different pieces of logic that are redirecting to "/"

Instead of this:

```
          <Route
            path='/sign-in'
            element={!user ? <SignIn /> : <Navigate to='/' />}
          />
```

Switch to this:

```
          <Route
            path='/sign-in'
            element={<SignIn />}
          />
```

If that causes a problem (ie, if you want to bypass SignIn and go right to `/` if the user is already logged in), you should add a `useEffect` call to SignIn and call `navigate('/');` there if necessary.

Comment: Thank you for your response, it makes sense and probably work but unfortunalety not suitable in my case, but thank you, you gave me a point of view.